# New Visual Studio 2019 C++ project doesn't have the asInvoker / requireAdministrator option?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, manifest

I had an old C++ project from VS2008 that I upgrade to VS2019, but afterwards I got the `warning MSB4211` that I couldn't get rid of no matter what I did.

So I rename the directory, created a new project, then copied over the source files, configured the project.   All compiling file, but I needs this app to run as administrator, however there is no option in the project settings.

I could swear I've always just gone to the project manifest properties in the project and choose the option I wanted. I found something on here about right clicking project, view windows settings, and it creates a manifest and that option then shows, but VS2019 doesn't have that option.

I have a separate manifest file I can include to do it, but why is it not in normal project settings?  How do I get it there?

TIA!!

Comment: _"I could swear I've always just gone to the project manifest properties in the project"_ - Yes, but that's only available for C#/VB.NET projects - not C/++ projects. For C/C++, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/understanding-manifest-generation-for-c-cpp-programs?view=msvc-170

Comment: I found it - it's under Linker / Manifest File.  UAC Execution Level.